# Hive unable to perform queries other than SELECT *

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running hive on my system where I have successfully created a database and a table. I have loaded that table with a csv file which is located on my HDFS.

I am successfully able to describe the table in hive, seeing all of the columns that I intended to be created.

I am also successfully able to run the simple `SELECT * FROM table;` query which returns an enormous list of data.

My problem starts whenever I try to run a query that is any more complex than that. Specifically, when I try to run a query that is selecting a specific column name or selecting any aggregate of data. If I try anything else, I receive this error message after my map and reduce tasks have sat at 0% for a while.

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapRedWork(Utilities.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushProjectionsAndFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.pushProjectionsAndFilters(HiveInputFormat.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ap
```

I have tried many different syntax techniques and performed numerous sanity checks to confirm that the table is actually there. What confuses me is that the SELECT * works while all other queries fail.

Any advice is appreciated.

Here is a query I ran with as many NULL checks as would allow: `SELECT year FROM flights WHERE year != NULL AND length(year) > 0 AND year <> '';` This query still failed.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * doesn't invoke mapreduce jobs.

But any complex queries involve map reduce jobs.

Please check the MR job logs.

Also this can be a data issue, Data might be incompatible with the table schema.
Please check with fewer rows.

Comment: I've had this exact thing happen with fewer rows so it must be some sort of MR problem. Although, I am on a multi-user system where other users are able to run these hive queries without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be your input data consists any null values. Because,

1. if you use `select all` command that job will not enter into mapreduce phase.
2. if you select any specific column it will enter into mapreduce phase. so you may get this error.

Comment: Yes some of the columns can have null data in them, although I'm sure the one I'm selecting has all of it's rows populated.

Comment: try to remove null values using where condition clause

Comment: Could you use an example? Do you mean something like WHERE value != NULL;

Comment: use value != NULL or value != NaN or get the length of string and check stringlenght > 0 like this.

Comment: Updated the post with an actual query I ran.

Comment: I executed your query, me too getting error. but if i replaced AND with OR it worked for me.

Comment: Did you replace all of the ANDs with ORs?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that none of the queries involving mapreduce jobs are running.

The **"select *"** query doesn't invoke any mapreduce and just displays the data as it is. Please check your mapreduce logs and see if you can find something which is causing this.